# Identifying if a map moveend event was user initiated

Tags: openlayers-3

I registered a 'moveend' event listener on my [ol.Map](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html). It's firing when the map is moved around by user input, but also when I call [ol.View.setCenter](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/apidoc/ol.View.html#setCenter) and [ol.View.setResolution](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/apidoc/ol.View.html#setResolution).

Is it possible to check the 'moveend' [ol.MapEvent](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/apidoc/ol.MapEvent.html#event:moveend) to determine if the event was triggered by user input or from manually changing the map view's properties?

Comment: It looks like there's no easy way (nor hard) to distinct the user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing the following.

```
map.on('moveend', function(event) {
  var mapView = map.getView(),
      moveInitiatedProgrammatically = mapView.get('moveInitiatedProgrammatically') || false;

  mapView.unset('moveInitiatedProgrammatically');

  // evaluate moveInitiatedProgrammatically's value and behave accordingly...
});

map.getView().set('moveInitiatedProgrammatically', true);
map.getView().setCenter(coord);
```

It's not ideal for the following reasons:

1. Introduces additional state information in the map's view.
2. Carelessly replacing the map view will lose that state information.
3. Requires setting a property before changing the view state and may be too easily forgotten.

However, it adresses my issue in the meantime.