# Open layers 3, map.on('moveend',..): Differentiate between user interaction and map.setCenter() calling

Tags: javascript, gps, openlayers-3, event-listener

I am implementing OL for a GIS application and want to add a 20 seconds timeout when the user scrolled the map, after which the GPS auto track function should resume.

For that I am utilizing the map.on('moveend', move_func(..)) listener. The problem is that it cannot differenciate whether the user scrolled or the position change came from map.setCenter(..). Although I could implement a state variable which is set to true every time map.setCenter() is called, this does not only seem un-elegant but also wrong in case the setCenter call and a user interaction would overlap.

So is there any better solution to this?

Regards

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/35163355/4640499 also without any solution.

Comment: What do you mean by _scrolled the map_? Zoom change?

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks basically any user interaction with the map, like swiping, zooming etc.